# How can I limit multiple functions with the same throttle?

Tags: javascript, throttling

I want to limit the execution of **two different functions** with the **same throttle**.

Let's say I have a function called A and another one called B.

I want to limit the number of executions of both of them so that if **A** is called at time 0, and the limit is 1000, **B** shouldn't get executed until after 1000ms has passed

Comment: Do `A` and `B` have return values? Are `A` and `B` synchronous or asynchronous? What is the context in which they're being called? These points should be addressed in order to provide a good answer to this question, preferably with a [mcve].

Comment: Rather than throttle them, you need to make sure that the updates on firebase are performed atomically. To do that, you might need to create a cloud function that performs the atomic operation using a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

Comment: Usually a throttle/debounce like this involves a variable scoped so that both functions can see it, and then using a `setTimeout` in both functions to reset the variable when it's "safe" to allow the action(s) again. Like the code snippet in [this example](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086)

Comment: There are a large number of ways to accomplish this, but they are all dependent on the existing design pattern you are implementing as well as dependent on the freedom of modification you have for the executing functions and their scopes. Without knowing the current design pattern, the freedom of modification, or the general scope of the functions, this question is not possible to answer without a large amount of conjecture.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts i already tried that, but then I realized the increment depends on local data too not just what's in the database, so I'm using firebase increment, which is atomic, but the local variables aren't changing fast enough that's why i need throttling

Comment: "depends on local data"? Why do `like` and `unlike` functions depend on local data? They shouldn't. Either your example is not comprehensive enough to clarify exactly what you need, or your current issues / limitations are self-inflicted due to a bad approach.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it's not just a simple liking, but it summarizes what the function does, no need to include details of no use in this question

Comment: If you re-read the feedback given by me and Travis, I think you'll find the details you've omitted are not in fact "of no use in this question". As it currently stands, it will not be possible to provide a valid answer without making several assumptions about your implementation that you've failed to provide a [mcve] for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i did:

```
doubleThrottle = (action) => {
    if (action)
        return this.A()
    return this.B()
}

let throttledUpdate = throttle(this.doubleThrottle, 1000, {'trailing': false})
```